# Bash identical string comparison with > or <

Tags: string, bash, scripting, comparison

Why does this line of code print ?

```
if [ "a" < "a" ]; then echo wow; fi
```

Also this line:

```
if [ "a" > "a" ]; then echo woow; fi
```

Comment: do you happen to have a file `a` in your dir? Because this is not checking strings.

Comment: I didn't but now I have it now, I think "a" > "a" created such.

Comment: @Nick Correct. `[ "a" < "a" ]` is actually equivalent to `[ "a" ] < "a"`; since `[` is a simple command, the input redirection `< "a"` can appear before `[` or anywhere in its argument list.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea [ was a program itself. Thanks

Comment: @chepner Did you mean redirection operator can appear before ] ?

Comment: Yes;  *simple* commands can be preceded by an redirection operator, so `< "a" [ "a" ]` is legal (but not, say, `< "a" while read line; do ...; done`, since `while` is a compound command). You don't see it often, but it some circumstances it can be more readable.

Comment: (And if you'll excuse a mini-rant, I think making `[` an alias for `test` is one of the worst design decisions I've ever seen.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not comparing strings. `<` is a redirection operator so in fact you are checking the success of such operation. And it is valid because you happen to have a file `a` in the directory you are running the command!

See what happens if the file `a` is not present:

```
$ [ "a" < "a" ] && echo "yes"
bash: no such file or directory: a
```

Let's create it and check again:

```
$ touch a
$ [ "a" < "a" ] && echo "yes"
yes
```

If you want to do so, use `[[`. From [3.2.4.2 Conditional Constructs](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Conditional-Constructs):

> **[[…]]**
>
> When used with [[, the < and > operators sort lexicographically using
>   the current locale.

```
$ [[ "a" < "a" ]] && echo "yes" || echo "no"
no
```

Answer (score 3):

To stop bash from interpreting the `<` and `>` as pipes, you can escape them with a backslash, or surround it with quotes like you would with every other string.

```
if [ "a" \< "a" ]; then echo "wow"; fi;
if [ "a" "<" "a" ]; then echo "wow"; fi;
```

The `[` aka `test` command will interpret its parameters as strings like any other unix command. Note that this won't resolve to true, because they are equal and thus not lexically sortable. You would need to include the equality yourself.

```
if [ "a" \< "a" ] || [ "a" = "a" ]; then echo "wow"; fi;
```

The `<` and `>` operators are not part of the [POSIX specification of test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html), so it is a shell-specific feature and may not work or behave differently with other shell implementations.